# Programming a distance

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, numpy

First of all: I am by no means a Python expert, so this question is probably rather easy. Secondly, I worked over more than 2 hours on this and now I've decided I needed help. I want to implement a distance in Python. The distance is given as follows:

[image]

Where ui and uj are vectors that are given. d is the dimension of that vector. For example: if ui = (1,2,3), then ui_0= 1.

Now, this is what I've come up with so far: (here, xi = ui and xj = uj)

```
def dist(xi, xj, k):
    distances = np.zeros(len(xi))
    min1 = (0, 0)
    min2 = (0, 0)
    for dim in [0, len(xi)]:
        for s in [-k, k]:
            min1 = abs(xi[dim] - xj[dim + s])
            min1[-k, k].min()
            min2 = min(abs(xj[dim] - xi[dim + s]))
            min2[-k, k].min()
            distances = max(min1,min2)
```

but it doesn't work. Does anybody know where I've gone wrong?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<input>", line 1, in
<module>   File "<input>", line 8, in dist IndexError: invalid index
to scalar variable.
```

EDIT:

Ok, I tried to look at the case where `k` is maximal and I've taken the comments of Riley and Wouda into account. I came up with this piece of code:

```
def dist1(xi, xj):
    for dim in range(len(xi)):
        for s in range(-dim, len(xi) - dim):  
            return max(min(abs(xi[dim] - xj[dim + s])), min(abs(xj[dim] - xi[dim + s])))
```

and I still get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 4, in dist1
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

What is going on?

Comment: The full traceback (added to the question) would be more helpful.

Comment: Is this was you want: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 8, in dist
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. ?

Comment: @querty 
edit your question and add it there, the comments are transient, the questions are not.

Comment: `[0, len(xi)]` is not a way to indicate a range, it is a list with 2 elements. and since python uses 0-based indexing, `xi[len(xi)]` will always throw an IndexError

Comment: @MaartenFabré: adjusted, but It still gives the same error. Is this also true for the [-k, k ] part?

Comment: yes, use range(begin, end) where end is not included. Thus `range(-k, k+1)` if you want all integers from -k to k included

Comment: I suggest you first get up to speed with python's basics. Stuff like [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/a-whirlwind-tour/9781492037859/) or [this](https://www.scipy-lectures.org/)

Comment: Interesting. Has anyone successfully implemented this distance? You also have to be careful with your k. It's possible in your algorithm that you get a larger dimension than your original one, which is impossible, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to forget `d` is a parameter also (since you compute `Dist_d^{ij}`, where `d` is clearly a passed parameter). Together with `k`, I think the following represents the snippet of math you posted.

```
def dist(xi, xj, d, k):
    min1 = min(abs(xi[d] - xj[d + s]) for s in range(-k, k + 1))
    min2 = min(abs(xj[d] - xi[d + s]) for s in range(-k, k + 1))

    return max(min1, min2)
```

Notice that Python will index negative values from the end of the list, which may or may not be what you want (in math, generally, not). So getting the arguments to this function right is a bit tricky, and you should build-in some checks to make sure all cases are handled correctly.

Comment: I don't think I forgot the parameter d. I just gave it another name: dim. And that dimension is fixed (it's the length of the vector), so you shouldn't have to specify it within your def()..?

Comment: @querty that could work, but what would `xi[d + s]` be when `d = len(xi) - 1`? Where did you get this distance from? It's not very rigorous mathematically, and I wonder if this ever made it into a published paper.

Comment: Yeah, as Riley stated, this can give problems. I think if you insert another maximum for the beginning and a minimum for the end, it could work. Like this: min(len(xi), dim + s) and max(dim - s, 0). I got the distance somewhere from a published paper online, but can't remember where exactly.